# After React Native Android rebuild, external images no longer show in Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

After I rebuilt my android folder (some settings got corrupted) images will not work (using Image React Native component). I'm not sure what the issue could be. Here is an error I'm getting:

```
E/MediaHTTPConnection: java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:560)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:293)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getSize(MediaHTTPConnection.java:466)
        at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:151)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1056)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1029)
```

To reiterate: I haven't changed the Image code at all. I think some deps auto-updated during the rebuild. It seems to be an okttp issue.

Comment: revert the operation using your git

Comment: I tried. It didn't fix it.